# Optimistic Concurrency Exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been battling with this error  for a while now. I hope putting it here will help.
I have attached by models and also the method call being made.
The error occurs when I try to savechanges on creation of a product.

Here is the Method by controller is calling to making the HttpPost request.

```
//Manager
public async Task<Envelope<ProductViewModel>> CreateProduct(ProductViewModel model)
{
    model.ValidateProductModel();
    var product = new Product
    {
        Name = model.Name,
        Price = model.Price,
        ImageUrl = model.ImageUrl,
        Description = model.Description
    };

    var category = await _categoryRepository.GetCategoryName(model.Category.Name);

    category.Products.Add(product);
    //_categoryRepository.UpdateEntity(category);
    await _categoryRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
    //_context.SaveChanges();
    ProductViewModel savedProduct = _mapper.Map<Product, ProductViewModel>(product);
    return Envelope.Ok(savedProduct);
}
```

Here is my model classes

```
//Models
public class Category : DbGuidEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public Category(CategoryViewModel model)
    :this()
    {
        model.ValidateCategoryModel();
        Name = model.Name;
    }
}

public class Product : DbGuidEntity
{
    public Product()
    {

    }
   
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public Guid CategoryForeignKey { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Then, here is my save changes method and by controller

```
//SaveChanges Method
public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, bool clearChangeTracker = false)
{
    var result = await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    if (clearChangeTracker)
        ClearChangeTracker();
    return result;
}

//Create Product Controller
[HttpPost("Create")]
[Produces(typeof(Envelope<ProductViewModel>))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ProductViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var product = await _productManager.CreateProduct(model);
        return Done(product);
    }
    catch (ShoppingMartException sx)
    {
        LogError("Error occured while attempting to create product:", sx, model);
        return Failure(sx.Errors);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError("Product Creation error occured", ex);
        return Failure($"An error occured | {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

ErroMessage:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since
> entities were loaded. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on
> understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."

Comment: you don't have an primary key fields

Comment: I do, my model inherits from DbGuidEntity

Comment: And the exact error message?

Comment: Oh, I thought I attached it..I'll edit right away.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally found a solution to my question.
Basically, EFCore for some reasons wasn't tracking my product entity.

I needed to first check the states of each of the entities inside the createProduct method like so.

```
_context.Entry(product).Context;
_context.Entry(category).Context;
```

And I found out that the product entity had a state of Detached (which means untracked), while the category entity has a state of Unchanged.

So, what I did was to manually instruct EFCore to track my product entity like so;

```
_context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Added;
```

This simply put the state of the entity to Added, meaning that it will be inserted into the database on calling savechanges.